# How to assign values to schema in shorthand

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, for-loop, foreach

I was assigning my JSON values to schema employee in shorthand, but I got the error as  the follow, but I got the error as Invalid shorthand property initializer, is this the syntactic way to do shorthand assigning

```
employee ={
  name={
    first = jsoncontent.first,
    middle =jsoncontent.middle
  }
  city = jsonContent.city,
  state = jsonContent.state,
  country = jsonContent.country,
  empId = jsonContent.empId,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any shorthand to parse convert JSON to another JSON like you mentioned.

You probably want to do this:

```
const employee = {
  name: {
    first: jsoncontent.first,
    middle: jsoncontent.middle
  },
  city: jsonContent.city,
  state: jsonContent.state,
  country: jsonContent.country,
  empId: jsonContent.empId
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to "punning" as the shorthand, which allows you to do this:

```
const employee = { name, city };
```

...that requires top-level variables to be present with the same name as your properties. JS syntax does not allow you to recurse into the source object's properties using punning syntax. Destructuring of the source object might help you out, however:

```
const { first, middle, city, state, country, empId } = jsoncontent;

const employee = {
  name: { first, middle },
  city,
  state,
  country,
  empId,
};
```

Or you may find that the usual inline object syntax like `Aritra Chakraborty` proposed suffices.